# What is the simplest way to find $\frac{n}{7}th$ of a line with mathematical proof?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, fractions, geometric-construction

I'd like to know if it is possible to find out the simplest way to get $\frac{1}{7}$, $\frac{2}{7}$, $\frac{3}{7}$, $\frac{4}{7}$, $\frac{5}{7}$ and $\frac{6}{7}$ of a line in 2-dimensional geometry. Straight edge and compass preferred as tools.

I have drawn one example which shows $\frac{1}{7}$, $\frac{6}{7}$, $\frac{3}{7}$ and $\frac{4}{7}$ parts of the line below. Dotted lines are half points of the square. Blue ones are aid lines. The last line from B to G intersects point H, which is giving hoped fractions of seven.

[image: n/7th of a line]

In addition I'm forward to see mathematical proof of the geometry.

Comment: Could you clarify which line segments you think are $1/7$ of the length of another segment?  Is your claim that $GH$ is $1/7$ of the side of the large square?

Comment: Good point. Line parallel to BD via H divides AB to one seventh. Figure not finished that far.

Answer (score 4):

From first chapter of "Four pillars of geometry", John Stillwell
[image]

Comment: So all this trick does is dodge the difficulty of measuring the length of $AB$? (If you knew this length then you could just divide it by 7 and set the compass to that radius...)

Comment: I am aware that straightedge-and-compass geometry has no ruler. I am just trying to get a bit of intuition for what this trick achieves. I am not saying that "dodging the difficulty of measuring the length of $AB$" is an unnecessary step.

Comment: The process of "setting the compass to that radius" is not easy, even if we know the length of AB.  (sorry, if I still misunderstanding your question)

Comment: If you have a ruler, then your compass can be assembled to also have a "ruler", i.e. to be able to tell you the distance it spans at a given setting. The point is that without a ruler, you only have relative distances. Thus you can make a line segment which is twice as long as a given compass setting (just draw two line segments of the same length adjoined to one another). But you cannot measure one length and then divide the *number* by 7 to adjust your compass to the right length. My question was about whether this is all that this approach does; I am fairly sure that it is.

Comment: I think the idea of this construction is that, we have the control over the proportions of the distances between A s on the arbitrary line L, we then "mapping" the proportions onto the line segment AB via the construction of parallel lines.

Answer (score 3):

Draw a line at an angle to the segment you want to divide, from one end of that segment. Mark off seven equal intervals on the line. Connect the endpoint to the other end of your segment. Then draw six parallels.

No time for a figure now.

Answer (score 2):

You can divide a line into any number, m, of equal points by:

At one endpoint of the line draw another line at an angle and mark off a unit measurement.  Extend the line are mark of m marks of measure.

Connect the m-th mark of the second line to the end-point of the original line.  We'll call this line Fred.

At each of the m - 1 measure marks construct a line through the measure mark parallel to Fred.  These lines will all intersect the original line

By Thale's Theorem of intercepts the corresponding segments of the original line will be proportional to the segments of the second line.  In other words, you've divided the lines into m equal segments.

We can take this further.  If you have a line measuring x (any x; maybe not rational; maybe not even constructable) and a line measuring y.  And any third line.  You can divide the third line it two segments with  x to y ratio. (One side x/(x+y) and the other y/(x+y) times the original).

Answer (score 2):

**Edited after the OP clarified (in comments) what the claim was:**

Here's how you can use coordinates to analyze your construction.  Let's put coordinates on the plane so that (in your diagram) point $E$ is the origin $(0,0)$, and the major grid lines correspond to a spacing of $2$.  Then $D=(0,7)$, $C=(14,7)$, $A=(14,-7)$, $F=(7,-7)$, and $B=(0,-7)$.

With those coordinates, line $EC$ has slope $1/2$ and is given by $y=\frac{1}{2}x$, and line $DF$ has slope $-2$ and is given by $y=7-2x$. They intersect at $G$, which has coordinates $(\frac{14}{5},\frac{7}{5})$.

Now we know that line $BG$ has slope $3$ and is given by the equation $y=3x-7$. Meanwhile, line $EA$ has slope $-1/2$ and is given by $y=-\frac{1}{2}x$.  These intersect each other at $H$, which has coordinates $(2,-1)$.

Now if you construct a line parallel to $BD$ through $H$, that line will have the equation $x=2$.  That line cuts the side of the square $CD$ exactly 1/7 of the way across its length.  So this construction does, in fact, work.

Now, whether this is the *simplest* construction possible is another matter. As the other answerers have indicated, there is a general algorithm for partitioning any segment into $n$ equal parts, where $n$ is *any positive integer*.  Whether that method is "simpler" than yours for the case $n=7$ depends, I suppose, on how you measure "simplicity".  The other method certainly wins in terms of generalizability: it's not at all clear to me how (or even if) your method could be adapted for other values of $n$.

Comment: Can you please show on answer how you calculate intersection points, i.e. how do we know BG slope is 3? Line parallel to BA at H divides BD to 3/7th and complementary 4/7th. So four fractions are generated. And right, if this is simple or Thales "way" is another question. Could we measure it by count of steps with compass and straightedge and giving different weight for each tools?

Comment: Slope (of non-vertical lines) is calculated as $(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$, where $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are any two points on the line. Once you know the coordinates of $B$ and $G$ you can just use that formula.

Comment: To find the intersection of two lines, write them both in the form $y=mx+b$ and then set them equal to each other and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to your picture and indicate that you can isolate the 1/7, 3/7, 4/7 and 6/7 elements, but not 2/7 and 5/7 portions.

You seem savvy enough to gather that once you have the 'unit' length segment that you can simply use the compass set to that length and easily segment the line piecemeal. Also, other learned respondents have already alluded to the traditional techniques for equal-parts division of a segment, yet neither seem to have been the method you seek.

The greater part of the solution I believe you are seeking has already been provided by yourself. I have included a twin picture, and the first rendering reflects the above-mentioned traditional solutions, adapted to accommodate your own workings re your supplied picture, with a few extra touches.
The second rendering is a compass-free (straight lines only) creation, again accommodating your supplied output.

Consider the manner in which you produced '**H**' (red point). If you proceed further using the same technique and create similar points for each quadrant, the framework is essentially all there. You just need to add in the green auxiliary lines.
(Where the green lines intersect the blue lines, two alternatives would also have sufficed:  by either bisecting the vertices of or adding in the diagonals of the square).

A further embellishment I opted to include were all the horizontal auxiliary lines (non-black) and the respective pink points. Although unnecessary, they serve to demonstrate the inherent symmetry of the framework, such that the equal sevenths segmentation can readily be produced both horizontally and vertically.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2YFL.png